# Flutter FireBase storing Picture with text

Tags: flutter, dart

as you can see from the title i wanted to ask if it is possible to store a document like a text document that contains a title and a text (I want to make something like an article) together with this „article“ I want to save an Image that can be displayed at the top of the „article“. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify more your problem? you can store images on Firebase Storage,  and using the `url` crated by the firestore to sore on your document, and displaying on your flutter web using a `NetworkImage`.

Understanding better your problem i can give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks four your help. I am trying to save like a document in which is text (Like title: „titlehere“ and text: „textetextextetx“). I want to do page on which should be a picture on top (I think you wrote the solution for that) and underneath I want the title from the article together with the text so what is written in the article. By the way I want to write the article by myself so not written by the app only read.

Comment: So i explained you what you should do... by adding your image on FireBase Storege, you`ll receive a link with you can save as {image : "<your url here>"} on your document, so you can access the string on your app and use as a url image on flutter.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how do I save an article (title + information(text)) as I want to save the article in the cloud so that the user does not have to download all the articles via the app download.

Comment: To do this,you need to learn how to use FIreStore,  when you can add documents with all the information and just pushe the desire document from the cloud.

Comment: If i helped please give this post a Up Vote and check that your question was answered.